# how to erase ubuntu on an usb stick

Tags: usb, xubuntu

I want to install ubuntu on my computer. I actually have xubuntu on a USB stick, and I want to remove it and replace it by ubuntu last version online. I tried make the operation with USB disk creator, but this message appear:

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.gi._glib.GError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 707, in _message_cb
    retval = candidate_method(self, *args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/share/usb-creator/usb-creator-helper", line 237, in Format
    part.call_set_type_sync('0x0c', no_options, None)
gi._glib.GError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Error setting partition flags on /dev/sdb2: Command-line `sfdisk --change-id "/dev/sdb" 2 0x0c' exited with non-zero exit status 1: 
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util sfdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Use the --force flag to overrule this check.
```

How do I proceed from this point?

Comment: You can use gparted to format the flash drive then burn Ubuntu the same way you burned Xubuntu on it

Comment: Use a partition editor tool to reformat the USB disk using the MBR partition table and then try again.

Comment: If the Xubuntu partition is ISO9660 as made by SDC, you can use the mkusb wipe function to restore the drive. http://askubuntu.com/questions/871970/usb-boot-drive-read-only/872405#872405

Comment: Thanks answerseeker, I downloaded gparted, but I'm not familiar with it. If I want to format my flash drive, how do I proceed exacly? (I'm looking in the tutorial, but it's pretty huge...)

Comment: Actually, I found a tutorial to use Gparted, and it seems I have to format my flash drive creating some new partitions. In this tutorial, they counsel me to format it to "fat32", but I don't find it in the options when I choose to "create new partitions". I can only choose in the format aix, amiga, bsd, dvh, gpt, mac,  msdos, pc98, sun or loop. Which one should I choose?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
dd if=/home/user/Downloads/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb
           <path to .iso>                                   <USB stick>
```